# Can't use a string who is bigger than 4 bytes

Tags: windows, assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I have started a week ago to "learn" Assembly using **NASM** on *Windows10*, so forgive me if this question is completely "*wtf*" for you.

I'm trying to use [**WinExec**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687393(v=vs.85).aspx) from kernel32.dll to run programs, like cmd.exe, calc.exe e etc...

[Here](https://github.com/peterferrie/win-exec-calc-shellcode) I've found this piece of code that works like a charm, *but* only if the *lpCmdLine* is equal to 4 bytes, I think that the problem is something related to the stack alignament, but I don't understand how I can solve the problem.
I've searched for 3 days a solution, read everything that I can found about assembly, but my brain is completely stuck.

In this sample code, I try to launch cmd.exe (7 bytes, 8 with the final 0x20 char [' '] to avoid the null byte), but doesen't works.

You can found the "problem" at line **62**

```
    [BITS 64]
SECTION .text

%define B2W(b1,b2)                      (((b2) << 8) + (b1))
%define W2DW(w1,w2)                     (((w2) << 16) + (w1))
%define DW2QW(dw1,dw2)                  (((dw2) << 32) + (dw1))
%define B2DW(b1,b2,b3,b4)               ((B2W(b3, b4) << 16) + B2W(b1, b2))
%define B2QW(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8)   ((B2DW(b5,b6,b7,b8) << 32) + B2DW(b1,b2,b3,b4))
%define W2QW(w1,w2,w3,w4)               ((W2DW(w3,w4) << 32) + W2DW(w1,w2))

; x64 WinExec *requires* 16 byte stack alignment and four QWORDS of stack space, which may be overwritten.
; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx
%ifndef PLATFORM_INDEPENDENT
global shellcode
shellcode:
%ifdef FUNC                               ; assumes stack ends with 8 on entry, use STACK_ALIGN if it might not be.
%ifdef CLEAN                              ; 64-bit calling convention considers RAX, RCX, RDX, R8, R9, R10 and R11
    PUSH    RAX                           ; volatile. Use CLEAN if you want to preserve those as well.
    PUSH    RCX
    PUSH    RDX
%endif
    PUSH    RBX
    PUSH    RSI
    PUSH    RDI
    PUSH    RBP                           ; Stack now ends with 8 (!CLEAN) or is 16 byte (CLEAN) aligned
%endif
%ifdef STACK_ALIGN
%ifdef FUNC
    PUSH    RSP
    POP     RAX
%endif
    AND     SP, -16                       ; Align stack to 16 bytes
                                          ; (we can't force it to end with 8 without dummy push and then or)
    PUSH    RAX                           ; Force stack to end with 8 before next push, also saves RSP to restore stack
%elifdef CLEAN
    PUSH    RAX                           ; dummy push to make stack end with 8 before next push
%endif

; Note to SkyLined: instructions on 32-bit registers are automatically sign-extended to 64-bits.
; This means LODSD will set the high DWORD of RAX to 0 if top bit of EAX was 0, or 0xFFFFFFFF if it was 0x80000000.
    PUSH    BYTE 0x60                     ; Stack 
    POP     RDX                           ; RDX = 0x60
%else
%ifdef FUNC
%ifdef CLEAN
    PUSH    RAX                           ; exchanged RDX
    PUSH    RCX
%endif
    PUSH    RBX
    PUSH    RSI
    PUSH    RDI
    PUSH    RBP                           ; Stack now ends with 8 (!CLEAN) or is 16 byte (CLEAN) aligned
%endif
%ifdef CLEAN
%ifndef STACK_ALIGN
    PUSH    RAX                           ; dummy push to make stack end with 8 before next push
%endif
%endif
    MOV     DL, 0x60
%endif
%ifndef USE_COMMON
    ; > Here I don't understand why doesen't works <
    PUSH    0x20657865 ; (space)exe
    PUSH    0x2E646D63 ; .dmc
                       ; I have already tried to use the macro B2DW, the same, crash at startup.
    PUSH    RSP
    POP     RCX                           ; RCX = &("calc")
%endif
    SUB     RSP, RDX                      ; Stack was 16 byte aligned already and there are >4 QWORDS on the stack.
    MOV     RSI, [GS:RDX]                 ; RSI = [TEB + 0x60] = &PEB
    MOV     RSI, [RSI + 0x18]             ; RSI = [PEB + 0x18] = PEB_LDR_DATA
    MOV     RSI, [RSI + 0x10]             ; RSI = [PEB_LDR_DATA + 0x10] = LDR_MODULE InLoadOrder[0] (process)
    LODSQ                                 ; RAX = InLoadOrder[1] (ntdll)
    MOV     RSI, [RAX]                    ; RSI = InLoadOrder[2] (kernel32)
    MOV     RDI, [RSI + 0x30]             ; RDI = [InLoadOrder[2] + 0x30] = kernel32 DllBase
; Found kernel32 base address (RDI)
shellcode_common:
    ADD     EDX, DWORD [RDI + 0x3C]       ; RBX = 0x60 + [kernel32 + 0x3C] = offset(PE header) + 0x60
; PE header (RDI+RDX-0x60) = @0x00 0x04 byte signature
;                            @0x04 0x18 byte COFF header
;                            @0x18      PE32 optional header (= RDI + RDX - 0x60 + 0x18)
    MOV     EBX, DWORD [RDI + RDX - 0x60 + 0x18 + 0x70] ; RBX = [PE32+ optional header + offset(PE32+ export table offset)] = offset(export table)
; Export table (RDI+EBX) = @0x20 Name Pointer RVA
    MOV     ESI, DWORD [RDI + RBX + 0x20] ; RSI = [kernel32 + offset(export table) + 0x20] = offset(names table)
    ADD     RSI, RDI                      ; RSI = kernel32 + offset(names table) = &(names table)
; Found export names table (RSI)
    MOV     EDX, DWORD [RDI + RBX + 0x24] ; EDX = [kernel32 + offset(export table) + 0x24] = offset(ordinals table)
; Found export ordinals table (RDX)
find_winexec_x64:
; speculatively load ordinal (RBP)
    MOVZX   EBP, WORD [RDI + RDX]         ; RBP = [kernel32 + offset(ordinals table) + offset] = function ordinal
    LEA     EDX, [RDX + 2]                ; RDX = offset += 2 (will wrap if > 4Gb, but this should never happen)
    LODSD                                 ; RAX = &(names table[function number]) = offset(function name)
    CMP     DWORD [RDI + RAX], B2DW('W', 'i', 'n', 'E') ; *(DWORD*)(function name) == "WinE" ?
    JNE     find_winexec_x64              ;
    MOV     ESI, DWORD [RDI + RBX + 0x1C] ; RSI = [kernel32 + offset(export table) + 0x1C] = offset(address table)
    ADD     RSI, RDI                      ; RSI = kernel32 + offset(address table) = &(address table)
    MOV     ESI, [RSI + RBP * 4]          ; RSI = &(address table)[WinExec ordinal] = offset(WinExec)
    ADD     RDI, RSI                      ; RDI = kernel32 + offset(WinExec) = WinExec
; Found WinExec (RDI)
    CDQ                                   ; RDX = 0 (assuming EAX < 0x80000000, which should always be true)
    CALL    RDI                           ; WinExec(&("calc"), 0);
%ifdef FUNC
%ifdef CLEAN
%ifdef STACK_ALIGN
    ADD     RSP, 0x68                     ; reset stack to where it was after pushing registers
%else
    ADD     RSP, 0x70                     ; reset stack to where it was after pushing registers
%endif
%else
    ADD     RSP, 0x68                     ; reset stack to where it was after pushing registers
%endif
%ifndef PLATFORM_INDEPENDENT
%ifdef STACK_ALIGN
    POP     RSP
%endif
%endif
    POP     RBP                           ; POP registers
    POP     RDI
    POP     RSI
    POP     RBX
%ifndef PLATFORM_INDEPENDENT
%ifdef CLEAN
    POP     RDX                           ; POP additional registers
    POP     RCX
    POP     RAX
%endif
    RET                                   ; Return
%else
%ifdef CLEAN
    POP     RCX                           ; POP additional registers
    POP     RDX
%endif
%ifdef STACK_ALIGN
    POP     RSP
%endif
%ifdef CLEAN
    POP     RAX
%endif
    RET                                   ; Return
%endif
%endif
```

To test if everything works, I get the *null* byte shellcode and launch from C++ with

```
void *exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof(shellcode), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
memcpy(exec, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));
((void(*)())exec)();
```

If I use **push 0x636C6163** (calc) everything works.

Again, I'm sorry if this is a **total noob** question, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

**Thank you for your time!**

Comment: In 64-bit mode, 32-bit `push` isn't available, but the size of the immediate is limited to 32 bits.  So you can't push a contiguous string; you'd have to `push 0x2E646D63` ; .dmc / `mov dword [rsp+4], 0x20657865`

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you! Now works! I have searched for 3 entirely days and the solution was only to use mov, I'm feel really stupid ahahah, thank you again!

Comment: Next time use a debugger to single-step and examine memory.  You would have seen the 4 bytes of zeros.  There are of course other possible solutions, like `mov r64, imm64` / `push`

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure!
I'm sorry for the duplicate, but seems that I was searching the wrong answer.
if you post your comment as answer I will mark as *accepted answer*.

Comment: I closed it as a dup because this doesn't need a separate answer, just a comment to explain why it's a duplicate.  (And I posted that comment before digging up the 2nd dup).  You don't need to apologize; it's obviously a duplicate to an expert, but if you don't understand the problem then often you can't find the relevant duplicates.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh, perfect! Have a nice day! :)

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi. I have another small question relative to the main question, if I try to concatenate a bigger string as *C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe* like that `PUSH 0x575C3A43
MOV DWORD [RSP+4], 0x6F646E69
MOV DWORD [RSP+8], 0x535C7377
MOV DWORD [RSP+12], 0x65747379
MOV DWORD [RSP+16], 0x5C32336D
MOV DWORD [RSP+20], 0x2E646D63
MOV DWORD [RSP+24], 0x20657865` 
The final string is full of garbage bytes, I have already read the other 2 question that you have linked, but I really don't understand why the final string is full of garbage. I think assembly isn't for me...

Comment: Did you reserve enough stack space?  Looks like you overwrite your return address if you use `mov` stores above `rsp+8` after one push.  Use your debugger to single-step, and/or set a watchpoint on the relevant memory to find out when it's being modified.  And BTW, NASM allows `push 'calc'`, so you don't have to work out the hex codes if your bytes are all printable ASCII.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, the problem was that I wasn't reserving enough space for the stack, now I have solved, thank you again!