# Why I can't call calc.exe but calc is ok in assembler x64 win32 API

Tags: assembly, winapi, stack, shellcode

I am currently studying shellcode writing. I have studied some assembly in the past but I jump from topic to topic in my studies and things are easily forgotten.

(the setup)

```
gcc --version
gcc.exe (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.2.0
nasm --version
NASM version 2.16.01 compiled on Mar 20 2023

#build commands
nasm -fwin64 -o file.obj file.asm
gcc -o file.exe file.obj
```

(the problem)
I wrote a program that calls WinExec with the 'calc.exe' parameter. However, the calculator app is not spawning. However, when I run the same assembly program with just 'push calc' string the calculator starts.
Why the difference? Does it have to do with LSB in some way? When I push *ca* and *lc* separately it does  not work either.

I am attaching the code below but I have tried many variants. Most of them run fine but do not spawn calculator. One example segfaults.

```
; define arch
bits 64
; make pic adresses
default rel

segment .data

segment .text
global main
extern ExitProcess
extern WinExec

extern printf

main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp,rsp
    sub     rsp, 32

    push    0
    push    0x636C6163
    
    ; variant code that also adds '.exe'
    ;mov     dword [rsp + 4], 0x6578652e

    mov     rcx, rsp
    mov     rdx, 1
    call    WinExec

    xor     rax,rax
    call    ExitProcess
```

A similar question was fixed with adding .exe with mov as in my examples that don't work. [Can't use a string who is bigger than 4 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675949/cant-use-a-string-who-is-bigger-than-4-bytes)

Calculator should spawn but it does so only on *calc* string pushed as dword with nothing more.

I tried the following (attaching stack dump after prepping for each example):

1. Pushing *calc* on the stack and adding *.exe* to it with `mov` instruction. (executable runs and exits ok but no calculator is spawned)

```
-exec x/16xg $rsp
0x5ffe70:   0x6578652e636c6163  0x0000000000000000
-exec x/16xb $rsp
0x5ffe70:   0x63    0x61    0x6c    0x63    0x2e    0x65    0x78    0x65
-exec x/16s $rsp
0x5ffe70:   "calc.exe"
```

2. Pushing and adding so the string in the end was *C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe*  (this causes segfault in KernelBase.dll)

```
-exec x/32xg $rsp
0x5ffe58:   0x6f646e69575c3a43  0x65747379535c7377
0x5ffe68:   0x636c61635c32336d  0x000000006578652e
-exec x/32xb $rsp
0x5ffe58:   0x43    0x3a    0x5c    0x57    0x69    0x6e    0x64    0x6f
0x5ffe60:   0x77    0x73    0x5c    0x53    0x79    0x73    0x74    0x65
0x5ffe68:   0x6d    0x33    0x32    0x5c    0x63    0x61    0x6c    0x63
0x5ffe70:   0x2e    0x65    0x78    0x65    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
-exec x/8s $rsp
0x5ffe58:   "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe"
```

3. Pushing *ca* *lc* *.e* *xe* in word chunks (executable runs and exits ok but no calculator is spawned)

```
-exec x/16xg $rsp
0x5ffe70:   0x6578652e636c6163  0x0000000000000000
-exec x/8xb $rsp
0x5ffe70:   0x63    0x61    0x6c    0x63    0x2e    0x65    0x78    0x65
-exec x/8sb $rsp
0x5ffe70:   "calc.exe"
```

4. Pushing *ca* *lc* in word chunks (this causes segfault in KernelBase.dll)

```
-exec x/8xg $rsp
0x5ffe74:   0x00000000636c6163  0x0000000000000000
-exec x/8bx $rsp
0x5ffe74:   0x63    0x61    0x6c    0x63    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
-exec x/8s $rsp
0x5ffe74:   "calc"
```

5. Pushing *calc* as dword (this is the only one that works)

```
-exec x/8xg $rsp
0x5ffe70:   0x00000000636c6163  0x0000000000000000
-exec x/8xb $rsp
0x5ffe70:   0x63    0x61    0x6c    0x63    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
-exec x/8sb $rsp
0x5ffe70:   "calc"
```

Comment: Have you checked the return value from `WinExec`? Also note you are putting the string into the shadow space. You should move the `sub rsp, 32` after the `mov rcx, rsp`

Comment: @Jester Hey Jester. I would need to dive deeper in the subject and testing. I moved the sub instruction for 'calc.exe' and Calculator started.  The return code before was 2 (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

Any light shed on why the fullpath version and the word push version would result in segfault?

Comment: You probably misalign the stack, but you did not show the code. Also you can look at the faulting instruction to see if it's one that requires alignment.

Comment: Actually the gdb log for case #4 clearly shows `rsp = 0x5ffe74` which is indeed misaligned (but even worse than I thought, it's not even 64 bit aligned)

Comment: @Jester. Thank you. I have studied about stack alignment and made it work. I was under the impression it must be 4 bytes aligned (must have picked this up from somewhere). Thanks again, I can now go forward with my studies.